# Need help with change of variables in very strange heat equation problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

in the ring $0< a<r<b$ if $u_{r}(a,t)=1$ and $u_{r}(b,t) + u(b,t) = 2$.

Also, am I interpreting $\nabla^{2}u$ wrong? Since this is a ring, should it be in polar coordinates? That part was not clear to me from reading the question

Comment: Are you sure that's the right formula? It suggests that the time-derivative of the heat has no dependence on the angle coordinate in polar coordinates!

Comment: @JohnHughes this is exactly the formula as given to me. But on reading it, I wasn't sure if it was in rectangular coordinates, and they were just calling $x$ $r$ or if it was actually in polar coordinates.

Comment: Addressing your revision: you're interpreting it wrong. $\nabla^{2}u$ means $u_{xx} + u_{yy}$, and you need to convert this to polar coordinates if you hope to express your answer in polar coordinates (which you should!).

Comment: @JohnHughes question for you: what are my independent and dependent variables here?

Comment: Your independent variables are $t$ and $x$.

Comment: I thought $r$ was my independent variable and $t$ was my dependent one.

Comment: No. The original equation is casted in Cartesian coordinate $(x,y)$, so before you do any transformation, your independent variable is $x,y,t$. (Apologise for forgettting $y$ in the previous comment). After you make the transformation from Cartesian to polar coordinate $(r,\theta)$, your independent variables now become $r,\theta,t$.

Comment: My apologies, I did not notice that your boundary conditions are given in terms of polar coordinates. But what I said still holds true, $r,\theta,t$ is your independent variable initially. Once you look for equilibrium solution, $u$ does not depend on $t$ anymore, other $u_t$ wouldn't be zero everywhere in your domain.

Comment: @CheeHan so $u_{t}$ does equal zero everywhere in the domain? I think maybe you meant to say "otherwise $u_{t}$ wouldn't be zero everywhere in your domain". Just making sure that's what you meant.

Comment: Yes you are right. I had a long day........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find equilibrium solution, you need to solve $\nabla^2 u = 0$ with the given domain and boundary condition. Now, in Cartesian coordinate $(x,y)$, $\nabla^2=\partial_{xx} + \partial_{yy}$. In polar coordinate $(r,\theta)$, it is given by
$$ \nabla^2 = \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\right) + \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\theta^2}. \label{eq:1}\tag{1}$$
Now, use the method of separation of variables. More precisely, we guess an ansatz of the form
$$ u(r,\theta) = R(r)\Theta(\theta), $$
but since the boundary condition is independent of $\theta$, we guess 
$$ u(r,\theta) = R(r). $$
Substituting this into $\nabla^2 u=0$ and using \eqref{eq:1} yields
$$ \frac{1}{r}(rR')' = 0 \implies rR' = C\implies R = C\ln(r) + D. $$
To find the constants $C,D$, we apply the boundary conditions (BCs) $R'(a) = 1$ and $R'(b) + R(b) = 2$. The first BC yields
$$ 1 = R'(a) = \frac{C}{a}\implies C=a,$$
while the second BC yields
$$ 2 = \frac{C}{b} + C\ln(b) + D = \frac{a}{b} + a\ln(b) + D\implies D = 2 - \frac{a}{b} - a\ln(b). $$
Hence, the equilibrium solution has the form
$$ u(r,\theta) = u(r) = \frac{a}{r} + 2- \frac{a}{b} - a\ln(b). $$

Comment: I could add more details about how to carry out the separation of variables method, but I am assuming you know how to do that (:

Comment: so I can't assume then that my problem is $\theta$ independent like JohnHughes suggested?

Comment: so if what you're saying is true, what happens to my boundary conditions, since they have $t$ in them?

Comment: I just added the boundary condition @JessyCat. The point is when you are looking for equilibrium solution, $u$ does not depend on $t$ anymore.

Comment: and yes, you may assume that your solution is independent of $\theta$ too, since the boundary condition does not depend on $\theta$. Put in this way, one of the boundary condition says $u_r(a,t) = 1$, this means that at the ring $r=a$, $u_r$ must equal to 1 for all $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$.

Comment: also right now I"m looking at the case when $\mu = 0$. I solved the equation in $r$ and got $R(r) = c_{1}\ln(r) + c_{2}$, where $c_{1}$ and $c_{2}$ are constants of integration. Then, I aplied the B.C. $R^{\prime}(a) = \frac{c_{1}}{a} = 1$, which implies that $c_{1} = a$. Then, when $R^{\prime}(b) + R(b) = 2$, this is $\frac{c_{1}}{b}+c_{1}\ln(b) + c_{2}$, but since $c_{1} = a$, $c_{2} = 2 - \frac{a}{b}-a\ln(b)$, is that correct?

Comment: maybe you should say something about separation of variables. I don't think I'm handling the case where $\mu = 0$ correctly.

Comment: just tell me is this an eigenvalue problem or not?

Comment: I really wish you could work out some more details about this. I just had a really bad panic attack about this problem.

Comment: I just put some details into the answer. I believe my answer coincides with yours @JessyCat (:

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you were given 
$$
u_{t} = \nabla^{2} u, 
0< a<r<b\\
u_{r}(a,t)=1 \\
u_{r}(b,t) + u(b,t) = 2.
$$

Now what exactly $u(a, t)$ means isn't clear to me, but I suspect it's this:

The problem has circular symmetry, so although $u$ would normally be expressed (in polar coordinates) as $u(r, \theta, t)$, the author's omitted $\theta$ entirely.

The Laplace operator in polar coordinates (see [this wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates)) looks like
$$
\nabla^2 u = \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial r}(r u_r) + \frac{1}{r^2} u_{\theta\theta}
$$
By independence of $\theta$, the last term is trivial, and your equation becomes
$$
u_t = \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial r}(r u_r) 
$$
where $u = u(r, t)$ satisfies $u_r(a, t) = 1$ for all $t$, and $u_r(b, t) + u(b, t) = 2$ for all $t$.

My guess is that this is amenable to some sort of separation of variables, but it's been 30 years since i've solved a differential equation for real. :)

Comment: ..and it looks as if @Chee Han agrees with me about the separation of vars. :)

Comment: Didn't know you were writing up a solution!

Comment: And I didn't know that YOU were. Fortunately, we seem to agree. All the best!

Comment: @JohnHughes check out page 8 of this bad boy: http://www.math.ttu.edu/~gilliam/ttu/s10/m3351_s10/c14_2d_disk_heat.pdf

Comment: FORTUNATELY for you, there's no $\theta$ dependence, so this reduces to "big messy fraction = 0" , which gets much simpler to solve.

Comment: @JohnHughes the only thing is then, should I have $u_{t} = \frac{1}{r}u_{r}(r,t) + u_{rr}(r,t)+ \frac{1}{r^{2}}u_{tt}(r,t)$ or $u_{t} = \frac{1}{r}u_{r}  + u_{rr}+ \frac{1}{r^{2}}u_{\theta\theta}$?

Comment: You want to find equilibrium solution, so $u_t=0$. Equilibrium solution also means stationary solution.

Comment: You should certainly not have $u_{tt}$. You have $u_{\theta\theta}$, which, because the solution is independent of $\theta$, must be 0.

Comment: And chee's point is well-taken: the left hand side can be set to 0 because you're asked for the equilibrium solution (which I missed when I read the problem).

Comment: @JohnHughes and so basically you're solving the Laplace Equation and not the Heat Equation

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: @JohnHughes what happens to my boundary conditions then?

Comment: Your boundary conditions are already expressed in polar coordinates: at $r = a$ you have one condition; at $r = b$ you have another. And since $u$ is independent of time (steady state solution!) and angle (symmetry!), that's all you need. It's a 1D problem at this point. (And this is the last I'm going to say about it: you'll learn something by working the rest out yourself.)